# Why does run command loads another console in window?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I am running my Java application made by gradle-gretty-plugin and the file for it is like the following:

```
:execute
@rem Setup the command line

echo "REDCA AGENT RUNNING.."
set APP_NAME=redca-agent-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
set CONFIG_HOME=%APP_HOME%\config

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\*

set CONFIG_LOC=--spring.config.location=file:%CONFIG_HOME%\application.properties
set APP=com.sds.redca.agent.Bootstrap
@rem Execute redca_agent
echo "%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %APP% %CONFIG_LOC% %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" %APP% %CONFIG_LOC% %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

When I run this in my local, it runs in same console where I run this command. And I uploaded to this application to the server where Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack1 is installed.

The problem is that it loads another console that is not the one where I run command. So If the application gets error, I can't see the log. Because the new console window is closed right after it show error logs.

I can't understand why the same application run differently.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround about this problem. I don't know the exact reason for that. But I changed Java and it worked.